# Jquery mobile ui-active class not added on reverse transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

So I have a multi page jQuery mobile app. I'm using $.mobile.changePage() to change between the different sections of the page. The user starts off on a form page where they select some options. This takes them to a results page and then they click on a result and are taken to a detail page.

This is all works fine. The class ui-active is applied to the multi page sections when they are active,

which shows them like so:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page-active {
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

However, if I click the back button, either from the detail page to go back to the results page, or the back button on the results page to go back to the search page, the class ui-active is re-added to that section and the page displays a blank white screen. The inspector shows a display: none.

There are no javascript errors in the console. My jQuery version is 1.8.3, JQM is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by changing all transitions to 'none' or 'pop'. Seems like using the slide transition in certain circumstances can break things.

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

We are dealing with this as well (during a fade transition).  One way to solve the issue would be to upgrade to the new jquery mobile (1.4.5 I think), which doesn't appear to have this issue.